# Portal.Site already defines a member called Page_Load with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application project that I am integrating with Sitefinity.
I am getting the following error message in my cs file of my MasterPage file:

> Type `Portal.Site` already defines a member called `Page_Load` with the same parameter types

Why does this error occur and how do I fix it?

Comment: I had this when I copied some webforms, I had re-factored the class name in code behinds, but not the designer files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this method defined in outer class with same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is not a Page_Load event on master page file.If you have a page_load event in master and current page then this error will most likely occur.
You can also add a reference to your project namespace .

Comment: master pages have a completely different page load than the pages that use them.  You can use both